# how to insert elements to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

am learning mySQL.Here i have a databale called `"practice"` and it has a table called `"users"`.This table has four column.

```
username,password,firstname,lastname;
```

i have a form field to get user input which will be inserted into my mysql table.But whenever i want to insert a new user to the table it gives an error.What might be the reason behind this problem??

> ERROR: INSERT INTO users (username,password,firstname,lastname,)
>   VALUES (Nelson,101a6ec9f938885df0a44f20458d2eb4,Nelson,Mandela) You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') VALUES
>   (Nelson,101a6ec9f938885df0a44f20458d2eb4,Nelson,Mandela)' at line 1

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']) &&isset($_POST['password'])){
   if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
$servername = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "practice";

$user=htmlentities($_POST['name']);
$firstname=htmlentities($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname=htmlentities($_POST['lastname']);
$pass=md5(htmlentities(filter_var($_POST['password'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));

echo $password;
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,firstname,lastname)
VALUES ($user,$pass,$firstname,$lastname)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

}
}
?> 

<form action='foreach.php' method='post'>

      name      :<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='name'></br>
      firstname : <input type='text' name='firstname' placeholder='firstname'></br>
      lastname  : <input type='text' name='lastname' placeholder='lastname'></br>
      password  :<input type='text' name='password' placeholder='password'></br>
      <input type='submit'>

</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: Since you removed the trailing comma in an edit and without marking it as an **edit**:

<strike>Remove the trailing comma in `lastname,` <=</strike>

Quote your values, since they're strings

```
VALUES ('$user','$pass','$firstname','$lastname')
```

On an added note:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

You also seem to be storing passwords using MD5, which is highly discouraged, it is old and considered broken.

For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Read these articles regarding MD5:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Comment: another **+1**for The best answer

Comment: @CodingHorror Thank you, I do my best, *cheers*

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra comma at the end of your insert `firstname,lastname,)`. Also, you need to quotes your value as they are `String`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,firstname,lastname,)
VALUES ($user,$pass,$firstname,$lastname)";
```

Should be changed to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,firstname,lastname)
VALUES ('$user','$pass','$firstname','$lastname')";
```